# Errors Logcat Android Studio App No Longer Runs

Tags: android

Working on a photo app to practice in Android studio. I have been messing around with taking photo's and sorting them by date, tag, and geolocation. My code was working two days ago now whenever I attach my phone to computer Logcat blows up and my app won't even run just crashes. A number of classes I have never coded are appearing as errors in my code now like, Handler/Looper/HandlerThread?

This is the only error I can understand so far from my Logcat:

```
2019-02-23 09:37:38.014 4066-4066/? E/SportWatchProviderService: You need to install SAccessory package to use this application.
2019-02-23 09:37:38.019 4066-4116/? E/SAAgent: SA_SDK_ERROR: Binding to accessory framework failed
    com.samsung.android.sdk.accessory.b: Is the Samsung Accessory Service Framework installed?!
        at com.samsung.android.sdk.accessory.SAAdapter.a(Unknown Source:174)
        at com.samsung.android.sdk.accessory.SAAgent.a(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.samsung.android.sdk.accessory.SAAgent$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source:33)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
2019-02-23 09:37:38.025 4066-4066/? E/SASdkConfig: Accessory Framework Not installed
2019-02-23 09:37:38.026 4066-4066/? E/SAAgent: SA_SDK_ERROR: exception: Accessory Framework Not installed
2019-02-23 09:37:38.026 4066-4066/? E/SAAgent: SA_SDK_ERROR: Samsung Accessory SDK cannot be initialized
```

Answer (score 2):

If this relates to the Samsung Accessory Protocol, I had the same error:

```
com.samsung.android.sdk.accessory.b: Is the Samsung Accessory Service Framework installed?!
```

In my case it was due to Proguard obfuscating everything in the namespace `com.samsung`.

As a fix, I added the following to my proguard file:

```
-keep class com.samsung.** { *; }
```

You could be more specific with this, but for this issue just know you will need to keep more than just `com.samsung.android.**` as there are other namespaces needing to be kept for the SAP registration to suceed, such as `com.samsung.api`.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had similar error with Android 11 (SDK 30). After decompiling SAP code ver. 2.6.4  I found that getPackageInfo("com.samsung.accessory",0) function is called.

However, according to Android 11 guidance additional permissions need to be requested in manifest:

> To provide better accountability for access to installed apps on a
> device, apps targeting Android 11 (API level 30) will see a filtered
> list of installed apps by default. In order to access a broader list
> of installed apps, an app can specify information about apps they need
> to query and interact with directly. This can be done by adding a
>  element in the Android manifest.

To make getPackageInfo working you'll need to explicitly provide all Samsung packages that SAP checks on by calling getPackageInfo method.

To fix the problem I've added the following lines to manifest just before <application ...> tag.

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.samsung.accessory" />
    <package android:name="com.samsung.android.providers.context" />
    <package android:name="com.samsung.android.app.watchmanager" />
    <package android:name="com.samsung.accessory.safiletransfer" />
    <package android:name="com.samsung.accessory.goproviders" />
    <package android:name="com.samsung.accessory.saproviders" />
</queries>
```

Alternatively you can use

```
QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission
```

but the latter will require some coding and asking users to grant the permission in real time.